# Will the Anniversary skins be locked and unobtainable after the event

Tags: overwatch

I'm specifically asking about the Anniversary skins as I heard somewhere sometime ago that the skins released just now will not be locked after the event is over, like all the Uprising, NY, X-mas, Halloween and Olympics skins.

I've seen the Olympics question, and as explained just two lines ago I am aware that all the previous skins are limited time only.
Due to the uniqueness of the Anniversary event and the rumor I heard I'm not sure about the last batch of skins.

Is it true or was it just a rumor ?

Comment: The only exception is some of the things that were added to the game that aren't marked as Anniversary specific, such as Reaper's Shrug victory pose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I voted to close this as a dupe because it has the same answer as the other event/seasonal skins/lootboxes.

This event may be more unique than the others, but the temporariness of the event and its items remains the same.

[Source:](http://playoverwatch.com/en-us/events/anniversary)

> "You’ll earn Anniversary Loot Boxes as you play, plus pick up a free
>   box when you log in between May 23 and June 12, 2017. Anniversary Loot
>   Boxes are also available for purchase—**but they’ll be locked away
>   after the event ends.**"

Comment: Maybe we should update the linked duplicate with this information, and close this one. That's sufficient evidence for me. Good find.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yep sounds about right.

Comment: @TimmyJim I updated the other answer and provided the new information, you or anyone else feel free to edit it more if necessary.

Comment: Don't answer a question if you're voting to close it :/

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Do you think it's better off being deleted or should I just leave it. I answered because of initial comments suggesting this could be different or unique. (That comment exchange has been removed however)

Comment: If you're voting to close a question, that means you believe it shouldn't receive any answers. Answering a question you've voted to close is nonsensical.